# Having trouble casting guid for where clause

Tags: c#

I am having a real issue here with a function which passing a guide into the function it works everywhere else and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
public bool DoesBomExistForHandeldId(string HandHeldId, string reference)
{
  List<BomComponentData> result = new List<BomComponentData>();
   try
    {
      using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataConnectionLive"]))
      {
         connection.Open();
         string sql = "select * from Fuel_BomTransAction where deviceId='" + HandHeldId  + "' and Reference = '" + reference + "'";
         logger.Info("SQL For the exist transactions");
         result = connection.Query<BomComponentData>(sql).ToList();

        }
        }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            logger.Warn("Error occoured on  DoesBomExistForHandeldId funciton " + ex.Message.ToString());
      }
      if (result.Count > 0)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
}
```

The error that I am getting back in my log is as follows

> 2019-07-05 10:47:26.3561 .lambda_method =>
>   BomTransferController.DoesBomExistForHandeldId =>
>   StockManager.DoesBomExistForHandeldId Error occoured on 
>   DoesBomExistForHandeldId funciton Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I have done a search and I tried the casting method same result the column is a unique identifier and its a valid Guid getting through

Comment: The problem is that you're using string concatenation to create a SQL query, not casting. That's what leads to SQL injection attacks and conversion issues like the one you encountered. Imagine what would happen if someone passed `1; truncate table Fuel_BomTransAction;--` as a `reference`. Use parameterized queries instead and pass both the `Guid` and the reference string as strongly typed parameters

Comment: Is HandHeldId a GUID? You have it as string, so maybe it's actually not a GUID at all when the error occurs?

Comment: Since `HandHeldId` is a string, there's *no* guarantee it's an actual Guid. Change the parameter's type to `Guid` and make sure you only pass `Guid`s around, not raw strings. This will allow you to catch any bad data as early as possible. If the data comes from user input or some file, it should be parsed to a Guid as soon as it's received.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the use of string concatenation to create a SQL query, not casting. This can lead to SQL injection attacks and conversion issues like the one you encountered. `HandHeldId` is passed as a string which means there's no guarantee that it contains an actual GUID. It could contain a number or something malicious like `'; truncate table Fuel_BomTransAction;--`.

`Query<>` isn't an ADO.NET method. I suspect you're using Dapper which makes it trivial to use proper parameterized queries.

The method should look like this :

```
public bool DoesBomExistForHandeldId(Guid HandHeldId, string reference)
{
    string sql = @"select * from Fuel_BomTransAction 
                   where deviceId=@deviceId and Reference = @reference";

    try
    {
      using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataConnectionLive"]))
      {
         connection.Open();
         logger.Info("SQL For the exist transactions");
         var result = connection.Query<BomComponentData>(sql,
                            new { 
                                  deviceId=HandHeldId,
                                  reference=reference});
         return result.Any();
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        logger.Warn("Error occoured on  DoesBomExistForHandeldId funciton " + ex.Message);
        return false;
   }
}
```

`HandHeldId`'s type is now Guid. The values are sent to the server as parameters named `@deviceId` and `@reference`.

This query is still too expensive. There's no reason to load the entire `Fuel_BomTransAction` row when we're only intersted in whether a match exists or not. The query could change to

```
string sql = @"select TOP 1 1 from Fuel_BomTransAction 
               where deviceId=@deviceId and Reference = @reference";
```

This will only return a single `1` if a match is found